# Returning 404 Error ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404

I have tried the following 2 things to have a page return a 404 error:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
}

public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

but both of them just render a blank page.  How can I manually return a 404 error from within ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you inspect the response using fiddler, I believe you'll find that the blank page is in fact returning a 404 status code. The problem is no view is being rendered and thus the blank page.

You could get an actual view to be displayed instead by adding a customErrors element to your web.config that will redirect the user to a specific url when a certain status code occurs which you can then handle as you would with any url. Here's a walk-through below:

First throw the [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) where applicable. When instantiating the exception, be sure to use one of the overloads which takes a http status code as a parameter like below.

```
throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound");
```

Then add an custom error handler in your web.config file so that you could determine what view should be rendered when the above exception occurs. Here's an example below:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404"/>
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now add a route entry in your Global.asax that'll handle the url "404" which will pass the request to a controller's action that'll display the View for your 404 page.

Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404", 
    "404", 
    new { controller = "Commons", action = "HttpStatus404" }
);
```

CommonsController

```
public ActionResult HttpStatus404()
{
    return View();
}
```

All that's left is to add a view for the above action.

One caveat with the above method: according to the book "Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010" (Apress) the use of [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) is outdated if you're using IIS 7. Instead you should use the [httpErrors](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors) section. Here's a quote from the book:

> But although this setting still works with Visual Studio’s built-in test web
>   server, it’s effectively been replaced by the `<httpErrors>` section in IIS 7.x.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add `Response.StatusCode = 404;` into the controller function to not return a 200 status along with the 404 page.

Answer (score 17):

I'm successfully using this:

```
return new HttpNotFoundResult();
```

Answer (score 15):

`throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound");` along with a [custom error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911212/how-to-implement-proper-http-error-handling-in-net-mvc-2/4912456#4912456) works fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
// returns 404 Not Found as EmptyResult() which is suitable for ajax calls
return new HttpNotFoundResult();
```

when you are making AJAX calls to your controllers and don't find any content.

When you are making classic calls to controller actions and returning Views you should use:

```
// throwing new exception returns 404 and redirects to the view defined in web.config <customErrors> section
throw new HttpException(404, ExceptionMessages.Error_404_ContentNotFound);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can personalize 404 result with

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "My message");
```