# Returning a custom 404 page with 404 statuscode in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to return a 404 status code with my custom error page.
However I keep getting 200 back, since the page does actual exists as far as the browser and server can tell.

What I have been trying so far is:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/404" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404"/>
</customErrors>
```

Where 404 is a route to the "page not found" controller and action.

I have also tried to set the statuscode with in my action..

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound(string locale)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
```

But that simply ends up with displaying the default Server error page (the gray-ish one with the red error message text)

Any ideas of how to get around this?

Comment: It looks like your question may already have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635114/returning-404-error-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and the solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522714/custom-404-page-not-showing-when-statuscode-is-not-200/):

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404; 
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; <---
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

You can find more information here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpnotfound%28v=vs.118%29.aspx