# Custom 404 Page not showing when StatusCode is not 200

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In my `web.config` file I have custom errors enabled:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
    <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

My `NotFound` action:

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;  //no issues when this is not set
    return View();
}
```

**The problem:**
This configuration works fine on a local server, but when I move it to a remote server custom 404 pages are not shown (IIS default 404 is displayed) unless the status code of `NotFound` action is set to 200.

Could someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also want to disable IIS custom errors by setting [TrySkipIisCustomErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true.

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404; 
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; <---
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Does it mean it was manually set on the IIS server somewhere to use its own custom errors over application's?

Comment: In IIS 7 **Classic mode**, TrySkipIisCustomErrors is set to true by default value. However, **I do not recommend running in Classic mode** since you can fix it by simply using `TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` while running on new **Integrated mode**.

Comment: Good to know, but my local IIS is set to use integrated pipeline mode though and custom 404 handling seems to work just fine (the example above works well on a few other servers too).