# Returning HTTP Result Code 404 With a Custom Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm have this controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxCall(string input)
{
    // ...
    if (!success)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        ViewBag.Output = ex.Message;
        return View();
    }
    // ...
}
```

This controller serve some AJAX calls. The web-browser send calls and I'm returning the result by HTTP-ERROR-CODES. I'm using two error-codes: **200** (success), **404** (failed).

This is how my View looks like:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Output)
```

My View just prints to the page the error message.

Everything looks fine until the page status code returning 404 error code. Then, the code ignore my "ViewBag.Output" message. Instead of my custom message, I'm always getting this message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

No matter which error occurs. As you guess, this is the system default 404 error code message.

How can I return a 404 error code with my custom message?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AJAX, I suppose that you send some JSON/XML strings or return 404. If so, use
string instead of ActionResult as the return type for your action. 
Furthermore you may find this question helpful:
[Returning 404 Error ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635114/returning-404-error-asp-net-mvc-3)