# MVC ignoring CustomErrors and redirects for 404 errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404

I have two websites, `A` and `B`, very similar in configuration and both running on ASP.NET MVC 3.
Both have an `ErrorController` and the following web.config settings for CustomErrors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

For both websites, all server exceptions are redirected to `ErrorController.Index()`, as expected.  For website `A`, `404` errors behave like any other server exception, and are redirected to `ErrorController.Index()`.  For website `B`, `404` errors never hit the `ErrorController` and the site immediately returns `StatusCode` `404` to the browser upon returning from `Application_Error`.

In an attempt to narrow down the cause of the problem I switched from the `<customErrors />` setting to this implementation:

[How to implement proper HTTP error handling in .NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911212/how-to-implement-proper-http-error-handling-in-net-mvc-2)

The this solution works great on website `A`, but still returns `StatusCode` `404` on website `B`, even though using this solution *does* hit `B`'s `ErrorController.Index()` and return successfully (then immediately returns the `404` code anyway).

Is anyone aware of some setting I may be missing, that treats `404` errors differently than other exceptions?  It seems like somewhere between the return of `Application_Error` and the response being sent to the browser MVC overwrites the response yet again with the `404` code.

Here's the debug output when I hit `Step-Into` on the closing brace of `Application_Error`, the point where the response contains the custom error reply.  Since this is all .NET code, I'm inclined to think the problem lies in configuration...

```
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.GetObjectData'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.GetObjectData'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.PrepareConstructorArgs'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.LogicalCallContext.LogicalCallContext'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.PrepareConstructorArgs'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext.ExecutionContext'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch'
```

And this is the exception thrown for `http://localhost/asdf`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The IControllerFactory did not return a controller for the name 'asdf'.
```

**Edit:** Fiddler log (as requested)

```
GET /asdf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.54 Safari/535.19
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=eedy1t51bn1ezpqpcyu50gyk; __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=eaKTV3bjxX1o2WirmR5C3bBEZcRvzLoXu/+Q4IjC7CJ93cth4Wh7hKP3Uj9/l54hWL8P2MIf1THR+sg0ZEQzOPK3uH99MdyVk+l9/aMBcleP/J8ZZOVAJqKX6TyCUt/jaCUVCexhzq0hbIcTE2Kj23ReINU=; .ASPXAUTH=0F432A1EA5723F00959C20465475F680E3E623729BB205533F91C83E9A23E96F845CDE8FEDCE9C35F87024FE299B473601D05ACAFBB4F69B31566FD538FC0CCC54E6A824A1B0DD99AAB3292D5077A8D1830DE6992C6AF2E62ED382CE9448AE0D5A25FEEB50BB95D026767B53C72DA879CF77503F22DC8EE1A7B4EAE774E052EBF005F006; AccountID=1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 23:08:08 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Close
```

**Edit:** It looks like the response headers have already been sent by the time `Application_Error` is called, so regardless what happens in that method or the `web.config` the browser will simply display the `404`.  Any suggestions on what would have triggered the sending of the headers early for site `B` and not `A`?

Comment: Have you checked the `httpErrors` section of your configuration? This is what IIS uses to manage how to handle exception states.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This was before even getting to IIS, just running on the local dev server.  The solution I posted ended up fixing the problem, but I can't mark it as the answer til tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** The response header was being set with code `404` and then closed.  I modified the controller factory to not call `.End()` and everything now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash. Otherwise, it could be trying to navigate to `http://localhost/asdf/Error`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error" />
```

Other tips, look at your IIS log.

Use fiddler to see what is being requested.

I use the following in my WebConfig.

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/Error404" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Currently I'm just on the local dev server.  The `/` didn't make a difference, but I'll keep that in mind.  It also doesn't apply to the second solution.  There's only one Fiddler log, and I'll add it to the question.