# How to implement proper HTTP error handling in .NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm referring to Darin's answer in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911212/how-to-implement-proper-http-error-handling-in-net-mvc-2).

I'm using MVC3 and I was wondering if this is still a way to handle errors?

In the rrror controller he has the following:

```
public ActionResult Http404()
{
     Response.StatusCode = 404;

     return Content("404", "text/plain");
}
```

Working from his code.. I want it to display the full URL, how would I do this?  So it needs to be `www.mywebsite.com/Error/Http404` and not just `www.mywebsite.com`.  How would I do this?  I thought that if I had the following code then it will display the full URL, but it still just displays www.mywebsite.com:

```
public ActionResult Http404()
{
     Response.StatusCode = 404;

     return View("Http404");
}
```

How would I get the value of ex that was set in the global.asax.cs to be displayed on this page?

I moved away from having my errors handled in the web.config because it kepted on have a aspxerrorpath in the querystring.

Comment: The fact is you can't change the URL unless you are doing a Response.Redirect from the server.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it from the global.asax?

Comment: Yeh! From the global.asax after handling the exception redirect to the corresponding controller action, but note that your exception will be lost in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx

This sample does not redirect to the error page but keeps showing the url requested where the error occurred. I hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding you want to redirect the user to a particular error page on exception and also from the error page you want to access the exception.

Here is what I've tried, created a base controller and overridden the `OnException` method. Inside the `OnException` method I'm doing most of the things you are trying in the `Global.asax.cs`.

Most importantly after handling the exception I'm setting a `RedirectAction` in the `Result` property of the `ExceptionContext`.

Also to access the `Exception` from the error views I've stored the exception in the `TempData`. From the `ErrorController` I'm passing the exceptions as `HandleErrorInfo` instances to the views.

Here is the complete code.

```
// BaseController
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
  {
    if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
      var action = "General";

      if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
      {
        var httpException = filterContext.Exception as HttpException;

        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
          case 404:
            // page not found
            action = "Error404";
            break;
          case 500:
            // server error
            action = "Error500";
            break;
          default:
            action = "General";
            break;
        }
      }

      filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(action, "error");
      TempData["error"] = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, 
                          RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), 
                          RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
      filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
  }
}

// Error Controller
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Error404()
  {
    return View(TempData["error"] as HandleErrorInfo);      
  }

  // other methods
}

// Sample controller derives from BaseController.
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  public ActionResult NotFound()
  {
    throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
  }
}

// Error404.cshtml
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "404 Not Found";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
  Last Exception: @Model.Exception
</p>
```

**UPDATE:** One disadvantage with this approach is we can handle the HTTP exceptions 404, 500 or whatever if it is thrown only from the controller actions.