# how to handle this in mvc 3 and iis 6 like stackoverflow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, bad-request

how to handle 400 bad request like stackoverflow in mvc 3 , iis 6 ?

eg: www.stackoverflow.com/a<

return 404 not found page , instead of a YSOD page

updated: why this does not work ?

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
     <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
     <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
     <error statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Look at this Question :how can i properly handle 404 in asp.net mvc  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: and check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911212/how-to-implement-proper-http-error-handling-in-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use customErrors tag of web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="UrlToRedirect" >
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="UrlToRedirect"/>
</customErrors>
```

Eg.:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Index"/>
</customErrors>
```

if UrlToRedirect = "~/Error/Index", Here, in this url, "Error" is the name of controller & "Index" is the name of Action method which returns Error View Page.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

In the "\Views\Shared Folder" of you application, you have "Error.cshtml" view page.

Comment: <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error" /> doesnot work , still HTTP 400 - bad request

Comment: i have Error Controller and Index Action